# General Class for MYSQL in electron JS

Tags: node.js, electron, node-modules, mysql-connector

I am new at Electron js and I came from a Web Development background,

Haw can I create a General class and use in any renders file? because it will be hard to add MYSQL connection in every function.

Example of one of my function inside render files to save users:

```
function insertUser(id,name,pin)
 {
   var mysql = require('mysql');
   const connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'localhost',
      user     : 'root',
      password : null, //
      database : ''
   })
   
   connection.connect();
   $query_check = 'select count(*) as total from users where api_id="'+id+'" ';

   connection.query($query_check, function (err, result, fields) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var getTotal = result[0].total;
      if(getTotal == 0)
          {
            $query = 'INSERT INTO users (api_id,name,pin_code) values ("'+id+'","'+name+'","'+pin+'")';
            connection.query($query);
          }
    });

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use [npm mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) not the older [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). async/await is a far clearer way of coding RDBMS interaction code in Javascript than the older callback stuff.

The generally accepted way to make a nodejs program have access to your RDBMS from wherever needed is:  by creating a MySQL [connection pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-connection-pools) right when your node program starts up. Make it globally accessible. This bit of code uses `global.mysqlPool` to hold the connection pool object.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

// Create the connection pool. The pool-specific settings are the defaults
global.mysqlPool = mysql.createPool({
  host: 'localhost', user: 'root', database: 'test',
  waitForConnections: true, connectionLimit: 10,
  maxIdle: 10, idleTimeout: 60000, 
  queueLimit: 0
}).promisePool();
```

Thereafter, your program can do this kind of thing wherever you need to do it.

```js
const [rows,fields] = await global.mysqlPool.query("SELECT whatever");
```

Each time you hit your RDBMS this way, the query code grabs a connection from the pool. (If there isn't one it creates one. If the connectionLimit has already been hit, the query code `await`s one.)

It runs the query.

It returns the connection to the pool.

It's almost magical how this pool of persistent connections, along with async/await, make the your code both easy to read and fully concurrent.